# Conflicting signatures with TypeScript and d3.merge

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have this piece of d3.js JavaScript code:

```js
  const paths = svg.selectAll("path").data([1,2,3]);
  paths
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .merge(paths)
    .attr(...) // more commands that refer to merged selection
```

However, the `merge` function breaks compilation with this error:

```
Argument of type 'Selection<BaseType, number, BaseType,
unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type
'Selection<SVGPathElement, number, BaseType, unknown>'.
```

I can fix this by substituting `merge(paths)` with `merge(svg.selectAll("path"))` but that is only a workaround. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. When we append svg-path, the variable path changes type and that type is the one required by merge method.

```
const paths = svg.selectAll("path").data([1,2,3]);
const p = paths
    .enter()
    .append("path")
p.merge(p)
    .attr(...)
```